# Send HTTP Headers as a Float in Python Scrapy

Tags: python, scrapy

I am trying at scrape an API that accepts some value in headers only in float form, when I send it in string form, it gives 400 Bad Request, and when I try to send headers in float form scrapy gives Error like this:

```
self.headers = Headers(headers or {}, encoding=encoding)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\scrapy\http\headers.py", line 12, in __init__
super(Headers, self).__init__(seq)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\scrapy\utils\datatypes.py", line 193, in __init__
self.update(seq)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\scrapy\utils\datatypes.py", line 229, in update
super(CaselessDict, self).update(iseq)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\scrapy\utils\datatypes.py", line 228, in <genexpr>
iseq = ((self.normkey(k), self.normvalue(v)) for k, v in seq)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\scrapy\http\headers.py", line 27, in normvalue
return [self._tobytes(x) for x in value]
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\scrapy\http\headers.py", line 40, in _tobytes
raise TypeError('Unsupported value type: {}'.format(type(x)))
TypeError: Unsupported value type: <type 'float'>
None
```

Anyone have any solution or faced similer kind of problem?

Answer (score 5):

First of all, headers are always sent as string. There is no data-type for headers like int, bool, float.

I might send an Api a header `X-RELOAD-TIME 2.0003355` but that doesn't mean i need `2.0003355` as float. And that is what the library is complaining

So in your `headers` make sure

```
headers["Name-Of-Float-Header"] = str(float_value)
```

and then call should be able to go through